# How can I draw the plan of one floor of the building using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg, canvas

I want to draw 2D floor plan on html page.

I have a data set looks like below.

**Dataset**

```
{
  floor:{
    "id" : 2,
     rooms:[
       {
        "id" : 21,
        "x"  : 0.0,
        "y"  : 0.0,
        "height" : 15,
        "weight" : 20 
       }
       .
       .
       .
     ]
  }
}
```

I want to get a plan similar to the image below

[image: floor plan 2D]

And I want to add tooltip when hover on room.

[image]

Is there a library you can recommend?

Comment: I don't think you need a library. You can quite easily draw SVG using coords. Another option is drawing on `<canvas>`, but in this case SVG is probably easier.

Comment: I would also favor SVG instead of Canvas. It will be easier to create the mouse hovers/popups in the DOM instead of having to create them in canvas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No library needed, draw the SVG shapes yourself, it is worth the investment.

Your main SVG elements are:

- RECTangles: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/rect
- Groups: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g

Door openings are white rectangles layered on top.

Alternative is use PATHs

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/path

My advice: Draw 5 RECTangles first, after that learn PATH notation (drawing the same RECT shape)

Overlays are 'mouseover' EventListeners that show/hide (Group)SVG, just like you show/hide HTML Elements with JavaScript

Start with typing SVG in a JSFiddle or CodePen.
If you use VS-Code, add the SVG Preview extension: https://github.com/SimonSiefke/vscode-svg-preview

You will have a first draft within an hour.

Note: Your current dataset does not have/show coordinates, so drawing is all up to you.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need more details in your data set. Here's code that produces the image you want... or something like it.

```js
      const dataSet = {
        floor:{
          "id" : 2,
           rooms:[
             {
              "id" : 21,
              "x"  : 0.0,
              "y"  : 0.0,
              "height" : 15,
              "width" : 15,
              "weight": 0.4,
              "gap": 0.8,
              "roomSize": 5,
              "corridor": 2

             }
           ]
        }
      }
    
      const roomData = dataSet.floor.rooms[0]
      const { id
           , x
           , y
          , height
          , width
          , weight
          , gap
          , roomSize
          , corridor
          } = roomData

      const areaWidth = width - roomSize - 2 * weight
      const areaHeight = roomSize - weight
      const area = areaWidth * areaHeight
      const areas = {
        room1: area
      , room2: area
      , room3: area - weight * areaWidth
      , room4: (roomSize - 2* weight) * (roomSize - 2* weight)
      }
  
      let html = `<svg
        version="1.1"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        viewBox="0 0 ${width} ${height}"
        style={style}
      >
         <path
          d="M ${x},${y}
             h ${width - roomSize}
             v ${height - roomSize}
             h ${roomSize}
             v ${roomSize}

             h -${roomSize + 2 * weight}
             v -${weight}
             h ${weight}
             v -${weight}
             h ${weight}
             v ${weight}

             h ${roomSize - weight}
             v -${roomSize - 2 * weight}
             h -${roomSize - weight}
             v ${roomSize - 3 * weight - gap}
             h -${weight}

             v -${height - 3 * weight - gap}
             h -${width - roomSize - 2 * weight}
             
             v ${roomSize - weight}
             h ${width - roomSize - 2 * weight - corridor}
             v ${ weight}
             h -${width - roomSize - 2 * weight - corridor}

             v ${roomSize - weight}         
             h ${width - roomSize - 2 * weight - corridor}
             v ${ weight}
             h -${width - roomSize - 2 * weight - corridor}

             v ${roomSize - 2 * weight}
             h ${width - roomSize - 2 * weight - corridor}
             v ${weight}
             H 0
             z
            "
        />
        <rect
          id="room1"
          x="${weight}"
          y="${weight}"
          width="${width - roomSize - 2 * weight}"
          height="${roomSize - weight}"
          fill="#fee"
        />
        <rect
          id="room2"
          x="${weight}"
          y="${roomSize + weight}"
          width="${width - roomSize - 2 * weight}"
          height="${roomSize - weight}"
          fill="#efe"
        />
        <rect
          id="room3"
          x="${weight}"
          y="${roomSize * 2 + weight}"
          width="${width - roomSize - 2 * weight}"
          height="${roomSize - 2 * weight}"
          fill="#eef"
        />
        <rect
          id="room4"
          x="${width - roomSize}"
          y="${roomSize * 2 + weight}"
          width="${roomSize - weight}"
          height="${roomSize - 2 * weight}"
          fill="#fef"
        />
      </svg>
      `
     
      const svg = document.createElement("svg")
      svg.innerHTML = html

      document.body.appendChild(svg)

      const showArea = (event) => {
        const id = event.target.id
        const area = Math.round(areas[id])
        console.log("Area " + area + " square feet")
      }

      const rooms = [...document.querySelectorAll("rect")]
      rooms.forEach(room => {
        room.addEventListener("mouseenter", showArea, false)
      })
```

The room area is shown in the Console rather than as an overlay, so you'll have to modify the code to show it as a tooltip.

Answer (score 2):

I think you would need an SVG based solution, because SVGs are efficient when there are user interactions like clicks & mouseovers involved. to ha there are a couple of libraries. 
I would recommend [Raphael.js](https://raphaeljs.com)

Its been around for a while, its simple to set up and easy to use. There are also a couple of good starter books that help you learn the whole library in a day.
[Raphael JS](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/raphaeljs/9781449365356/), [Raphael JS Starter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1782169857)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [D3.js](https://d3js.org/), although I don't know if it will be an overkill for your usecase. D3.js is an awesome library to create data-driven documents, i.e when you have some custom data, and you want to use that data to manipulate the HTML DOM elements. It also supports dynamic runtime behaviour and animation.

- An easy quickstart for d3.js is https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-basic-shapes-and-d3js.
- [Freecodecamp tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4t6qfHZ6Tw)
- Drawing Rectangle blocks using D3.js - https://bl.ocks.org/romsson/568e166d702b4a464347 (This example is a bit interactive).
- This example shows how to show Tooltips while creating a document with d3.js https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/a22c42db65eb00d4e369